# Is Ruby's Net::HTTP threadsafe?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

Is Ruby's Net::HTTP threadsafe?

(Aside from the version_1_1 and version_1_2 methods which it explicitly says aren't)

Comment: Assuming you're not on MacRuby or JRuby, does it matter? The runtime isn't really multithreaded anyway, only one thread can run at a time.

Comment: Doesn't matter? So if net:http maintains some global state for your connection and the runtime switches back and forth between two threads, nothing will go wrong? I don't know if net:http is threadsafe or not, but I do know your answer is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't count on it.

In 2008, [matz wrote](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/174086#762788):

> For MRI (1.8.x) and YARV (1.9.x), every C implemented methods are
>   protected by GIL (Global Interpreter Lock), so that you don't have to
>   worry about.  But it might depend on each implementation.

Net::HTTP is in stdlib, which means it is not implemented in C (or at least, not fully implemented in C). I am assuming that matz's note on the GIL is still correct today, which would imply that the GIL would not be placed on Net::HTTP. Therefore, I doubt it would be threadsafe.

I have unfortunately not found definitive evidence in the docs for the current version of Ruby, though I feel it is also worth mentioning this bit from [Concurrency in jruby](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/Concurrency-in-jruby):

> At least these classes [core classes and classes in the stdlib] are
>   not considered thread-safe, and if you intend to mutate them
>   concurrently with other operations you will want to introduce locking
>   (e.g. with Mutex): String, Array, Hash, and any data structures
>   derived from them.

I feel it would be best to play it safe by either adding locks around Net::HTTP or using a threadsafe alternative.

Comment: How would you add locks @nick

Comment: It depends on your use case, you probably just need to treat each request as atomic. If you need help with that either open a new question or just use another library that's proven to be threadsafe.